# Trying to install MONO/ASP.NET - but cant figure out which Linux distribution to use for a server

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono, amazon-ec2

**Windows server/IIS is no problem, but Linux is... for me...**

I am experienced with Windows server administraton and IIS, but I would like to try MONO framework on a Linux-server.

**Amazon AWS ECS**

For this I will use an Amazon AWS EC2 instance. But I cant decide which Linux distribution is best for "me" nor which images/add ons I need to get it up and running.

I would like something that is simple to config with multiple virtual hosts (domains/subdomains), as I am trying to see if this could work instead of Windows IIS.

My new future CMS-engine setup will utilize many different clusters of webservers and using Windows IIS for this task could get quite expensive with a pure Microsoft Solution.

As I would like the customers to be able to choose their own platform, I need to figure out if MONO is able to support my development - and learn what parts I need to redo so its cross-platform.

**MONO and NGINX???**

I have tried to install MONO on my Windows 7 machine and played around with the ways to get ASP.NET to work with NGINX webserver, but - now I want to move along to the "real deal" eg. Linux server.

I know about ports, NAT, IP etc. so I am not afraid of a little ASCII config, as long as its logical.

Where do I start? Do I use a Linux with GUI or do I compile some kinda util or perhaps ... and thats why I ask here: do I have to program/compile everything myself on Linux to get a MONO webserver up and running?

I hope some experienced AWS/MONO geeks are listning here. :o)

My own idea was an Ubunto Server, but as a none-Linux expert I have a hard time understanding which distribution is best for which purpose.

Comment: I use Debian, it's mono lags a little but you can compile from source. Mono is/was developed by Novell so Suse Linux comes to mind

Comment: Is this a good tool: http://susestudio.com ?

Comment: Yes, depending on your needs. I'd do that only after gaining a lot of experience locally :)

Comment: My needs are: 

1) figure out how to install the safest/most stable/easiest Linux server for running ASP.NET with MONO... cant make sense about which distribution is most usefull for what.

2) figure out how to config this on Amazon AWS. 

3) perhaps a MySQL, but might stick with other DB's on other images

Comment: susestudio seems nice for that. MySQL on AWS: see Eric Hammond's tutorials (alestic.com). They're the best

Answer (score 1):

I would just recommend Suse Linux. Since Mono is largely sponsored by Novell, who is also the developer of Suse Linux and they have good integration. It's also a good distribution.

http://www.novell.com/products/mono/

Comment: okay? interesting, I will have a look. As I am totally Linux newbie, I how this is logical to a windows user... ouch!

Comment: SUSE Linux isnt free I guess? thought Linux and OpenSource would release us from licenses?

Comment: I think they are talking about the enhancement/extension to mono that's not free. [TANSTAAFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain't_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch).

Comment: Sure but the link you provided states "download eval" in the upper right corner.

Comment: Right, that's for the *SUSE Linux Enterprise Mono Extension*, not Suse Linux itself. They apparently developed a mono extension that enables better interoperability with Microsoft stuff. But you don't have to use that. I linked it thinking as a newbie you might be interested so you don't have to do all that hard work yourself.

Comment: BTW, the also provide a virtual machine image with OpenSUSE and the latest Mono pre-configured. See the [getting started page](http://www.mono-project.com/GettingStartedWithMonoVS).

Comment: Yeah, I've tried those. Got a nice MONO running in a local VMware here. But my question is about Amazon AWS - dont take me wrong, I do appriciate your effort. I just dont understand the answers.